# Android Intent share Image from url path without saving in local

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

Hi I need to share image using intent the image is stored in server path ho to achieve it

```
private void shareContent(String urlpath)
{
    URL url = null; //Some instantiated URL object
    try {
        url = new URL(urlpath);
        URI uri = url.toURI();


    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    URI screenshotUri = uri;
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the method that I am using when share button is clicked and I am working in this list adapter

Comment: What is urlpath?

Comment: check it here and use as a link share instead of pic https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents

Comment: url path actually the image location like http://www.flooringvillage.co.uk/ekmps/shops/flooringvillage/images/request-a-sample--547-p.jpg

Comment: So you have code. Well what does not work? What is your problem?

Comment: i am getting sharing failed error and now its working refer this url [link]https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents Thanks King of Masses

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`EXTRA_STREAM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) states that the value needs to be a `content` URI. Technically nothing is stopping you from putting a `http` URI there. But 99% of receiving apps won't support that.

What you could do is write a `ContentProvider` that accesses the contents of a `http` URI and streams them to the receiving application. Kind of like [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), but for `http` URIs instead of files.
Or, prior to sharing, you download the image, write it to a local file and expose it using `FileProvider`.